# breaking polylines on join spot in autocad - any lisp function?

Tags: lisp, autocad, autocad-plugin

i am trying to break a poly line where an other poly line has joined the first line. for example in three ways that there are two lines, (one main road and one  by-way) i want to break  the main road on the joint spot of two poly lines and make 3 individual lines.
so is there any lisp function or something like that , which can do the routine for all the poly lines in my map ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i find a solution for this problem, 
there is lisp programm, free to download, named QBRICK
you can download it from here : http://www.synapse-informatique.com/qbrick_en.htm 
but it only supports 2000 - 2008

Answer (score 0):

If i'd understand you as goog as I think, u should just use "ctrl+A" and "X" "Space", with this u're going to explode all the map, If i'm not right just redo the question and send me a link.

(I'm studying english yet, so, sorry if I had interpreted you not so good.)